# windows: Is the term "basic disk" the same as "Simple Volume"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-server, disk-management

While doing some disk management operations with 4 SSD drives on my windows-10 machine, I read some Microsoft documentation 2022-01-10 that says "dynamic disks" (i.e. Disk Management's "spanned", "striped", "mirror", "raid 5" volumes) ["have been deprecated and we don't recommend using them anymore" 2022-01-10 article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk).

The article talks about converting to "basic disk" but in windows-10 there is no such option in Disk Management GUI (is the term "basic disk" a windows-server only term?).

In Windows-10 Disk Management when you right-click an unallocated harddrive you get the options "Simple Volume", "Spanned Volume", "Striped Volume", "Mirrored Volume", "Raid 5 Volume" (option is gray because apparently the option for "Raid 5 Volume" is only available in windows-server according to what I have).

#### Is the technical term "basic disk" the same as "simple volume" in windows-10 Disk Management?

Comment: “When all volumes on the disk have been deleted, right-click the disk, and then click Convert to Basic Disk”

Comment: Right. I read that part in the manual. In windows 10 there is no option for "basic disk" and so I'm asking this question. In my question I listed the options I get and none of them are "basic disk".

Comment: Yes; There should be. The reason your not getting the option is because the drive is unallocated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Basic disk" refers to the *whole* disk – it means the disk uses standard MBR or GPT partitioning (as opposed to Microsoft LDM), and therefore can only *contain* simple volumes.

The opposite is "Dynamic disk" which uses the LDM partitioning style (Logical Disk Manager; the Windows equivalent of LVM for Linux) and can contain spanned/mirrored/striped volumes in addition to simple volumes.

However, if you only have simple volumes, that doesn't automatically mean they're on a "Basic" MBR/GPT disk – it could still be in "Dynamic" LDM format.

As this is a disk-level property, not a volume-level one, it will be shown in disk information to the left of physical partitions:

[image: Screenshot of the disk information block. It says: "Disk 0; Basic; 223.56 GB; Online"]

Right-clicking that area will offer you an option to convert a Basic MBR disk to Dynamic LDM, or the other way around (as long as it has Simple volumes only).

[image: Screenshot of the same block with its right-click menu. It has options "New Spanned/Striped/Mirrored/RAID-5 Volume", "Convert to Dynamic Disk" and "Convert to MBR Disk", all of them grayed out.]

Comment: i was right clicking the GUI where the screenshot shows "100 MB" and this brings up a menu with the five options i listed. **the trick as this solutions says is to click the part that says "Disk 0"** and then you get a new menu with the "Convert to Dynamic Disk" or "Convert to Basic Disk".

Comment: quick note: my disks are USB drives and so when you try to do "Convert to Dynamic Disk" or try to create a spanned/striped/mirrored/raid-5 then you get an error dialog "Operation is not supported" (according to superuser the operation is not supported for USB/external disks and only for internal disks).

Answer (score 0):

The two terms are quite different. A basic disk can contain multiple
simple volumes.

[Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks)
are the two formats of disks on Windows.

The term basic disk refers to a disk that contains partitions,
such as primary partitions and logical drives, which in turn are
formatted with a file system to become a volume for file storage.
Basic disks provide a simple storage solution.

The other disk format is the Dynamic.
Dynamic disks allow more evolved architecture,
such as volumes that span multiple disks (spanned and striped volumes)
and fault-tolerant volumes (mirrored and RAID-5 volumes).
Like basic disks, dynamic disks can use the MBR or GPT partition styles on
systems that support both.

A simple volume is a portion of a physical disk that functions as though
it were a physically separate unit. A simple volume can consist of a single
region on a disk or multiple regions of the same disk that are linked
together.

The simple volume can only be created on a dynamic disk,
while the primary partition can only be created on a basic MBR or GPT disk.

When extending the simple volume to include unallocated space
on the same disk it remains a simple volume.

When extending a simple volume to include unallocated space on
other disks on the same computer, this creates a spanned volume.

References:

- [Basic and Dynamic Disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks)
- [Volume Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vds/volume-object)